# Holding or selling a laptop due to unpaid repairs

Tags: england-and-wales, costs

In the UK are the any laws which stipulate what can be done when a repair is carried out on an item but not paid for?

I have been told that you can hold on to the item until payment is received but I don't know the law behind that.

Also, at any point, can you sell the item to reclaim costs?

The items I am interested in are laptops,  Pcs, and other related electronic devices.

Comment: I just found this: https://www.canlii.org/en/bc/laws/stat/rsbc-1996-c-404/latest/rsbc-1996-c-404.html
would this cover my question?

Comment: that's a Canadian website, it is not necessarily going to apply in the UK. Typically in the UK if a customer refuses to pay for a service delivered, you have to take them to a small claims court (although the threat is usually enough to make them cough up). Refusing to return a laptop you have repaired until the customer has paid is a grey area AFAIK. It also depends *why* the customer refuses to pay - do they question your work (because their rights as a customer cover that).

Answer (score 1):

In the USA, there's a concept known as a "mechanic's lien."  The lien applies to repairs done to a vehicle (an asset).  In the USA, this applies over a broad class of items.

Comment: Is there anything similar in England and Wales?